# Comparing Multiple Date with between Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `reservations` 
WHERE  '2014-09-04' BETWEEN check_in AND check_out
```

In another case, I need to compare this check_in and check_out field with multiple dates. This query could solve that problem

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `reservations` 
WHERE  '2014-09-04' BETWEEN check_in AND check_out 
        OR '2014-09-09' BETWEEN check_in AND check_out
```

But this query is not efficient if I have a lot of date to compare. Anybody have solution to make this query shorter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorter query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.* 
 FROM reservations r
 JOIN (
  SELECT '2014-09-04' AS dt UNION
  SELECT '2014-09-09' AS dt
 ) dates ON dates.dt BETWEEN r.check_in AND r.check_out
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have indexes on `check_in` and `check_out`, then multiple conditions with `or` is the best approach.  If you do have indexes on these columns and they are being used in the first case, then try using `union`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `reservations` 
WHERE '2014-09-04' BETWEEN check_in AND check_out 
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM   `reservations` 
WHERE  '2014-09-09' BETWEEN check_in AND check_out ;
```

Note that `union` incurs an overhead of removing duplicates.  I am using it because you could have duplicates in the result and, presumably, you do not want them.  In general, I recommend using `union all` when possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check for overlaps:

```
SELECT *
FROM reservations
WHERE '2014-09-04' <= check_out AND '2014-09-09' >= check_in
```